# Multi-threading recursive directory file hasher

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tree, traversal

I have just finished a program that takes a starting directory, checks all sub directories and hashes all files on the way. I achieved this using boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator.

I'm now trying to come up with a way to multi-thread this to improve the performance. I have a few rough ideas and would like some feedback.

1. Find the first set of sub directories and split them between threads. If a thread finishes before the other it can task-steal to help it out.
2. One thread (or more) go through all directories adding all files to a task queue waiting to be hashed and output to the console by another thread.

This might result in a slower program than the non-threaded version, however I still want to try it and see how the performance differs.

Comment: You may find it quite a bit slower on spinning rust discs, but probably faster on SSDs. Note that Filesystem's directory iterator is extremely slow and will not perform well in large directories.